# How to use a different model in a partial view (Frame inside @RenderBody())

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm using Razor (as in MVC 3) for a facebook application.
My **_Layout.cshtml** calls `RenderBody()` which returns the body with the data we asked the facebook user to provide. If the user falls into a category (for example, he is an admin in a certain group), I allow him to send information to the application while regular users can only view it.
For that, I have in my **Index.cshtml**:

```
@using samuraiscentraltrader.Models
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Facebook.Models
@model MyAppUser
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
<article class="intro">
<span id="profilePicture">
    @if (Model.ProfilePicture != null && Model.ProfilePicture.Data != null)
    {
        <img src="@Model.ProfilePicture.Data.Url" />
    }
</span>
<h3>Welcome @Model.Name</h3>
@*<label>Email: @Model.Email</label>*@

@if(Model.Groups != null && Model.Groups.Data != null && Model.Groups.Data.Count > 0 &&
    Model.Groups.Data.Any(g=> g.ID=="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" && g.Administrator == "True"))
{
    <div>
        @Html.Partial("_Admin")
    </div>
}
else
{
    <p> blah blah blah.</p>
}
</article>
```

See the line `@Html.Partial("_Admin")`? Is that the right approach?

In my **_Admin.cshtml**, I have

```
@model samuraiscentraltrader.Hubs.TradeInfoHub

<fieldset>
    <legend>TradeInfoHub</legend>

    <div class="display-label">
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.msg)
    </div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.msg)
    </div>
</fieldset>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=Model.PrimaryKey */ }) |
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</p>
```

I got the following exception:
*System.InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'samuraiscentraltrader.Models.MyAppUser', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'samuraiscentraltrader.Hubs.TradeInfoHub'.*

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider changing the title of the question to "How to use a different model in a partial view."

Answer (score 0):

The surrounding declares its model type as `@model MyAppUser`, the partial uses `@model [...].TradeInfoHub`. The model is passed down the partial view unless you provide a different model. That's why you're seeing the exception.

As the view expects a TradeInfoHub, you need to provide it:

```
 @Html.Partial("_Admin", /*a TradeInfoHub instance*/)
```

Alternatively, you could invoke a child action like

```
@Html.Action("ShowAdminContent", "AdminTools")
```

`AdminToolsController.ShowAdminContent` would then render the appropriate content. This way the original view does not need to know about the model of the "frame". I prefer the child-action approach if I need to compose pages like this.